# Uploading Pictures in Rails 3 (follow-up)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, image

This is a follow-up question to [Uploading Pictures Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857187/uploading-pictures-ruby-on-rails)

I have read about Paperclip and watched the railscast on it. It seems to come highly recommended, but the post is quite old and most pages I am finding about it are from 2009ish.

I was wondering what recommendations people had for uploading and managing photos in Rails 3? Still Paperclip, or are there new gems or methods that I should consider in building photo functionality into a site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) is another option as well. I like that its a little more de-coupled from your models than Paperclip.

Comment: interesting!! it looks also to be a much simpler set-up/ much quicker to learn. Would you agree? And, do you know how well this works on heroku?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with Heroku. The setup is super easy, yes.